# Matching inner parentheses expressions in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to parse Jinja functions on the frontend that look like so:

```
{{ some_tag('firstarg', 'secondarg', 'thirdarg', 'fourtharg') }}
```

But I don't know how many parameters there will be. So what did I do? I wrote the following regex:

```
{{\W*some_tag\W*\((['"](.*)['"],\W*){0,}['"](.*)['"]\)}}
```

However, when I run this regex, I get output like:

```
matches = regex.exec("{{ some_tag('firstarg', 'secondarg', 'thirdarg', 'fourtharg') }}")

matches:
  "{{ some_tag('firstarg', 'secondarg', 'thirdarg', 'fourtharg')}}",
  "'firstarg', 'secondarg', 'thirdarg'",
  "'firstarg', 'secondarg', 'thirdarg'",
  "'fourtharg'"
```

But this is not what I want. I need a way to match the inner parentheses so that I just have variables that correspond to `firstarg`, `secondarg`, `thirdarg`, and `fourtharg`.

How do I get this?

Comment: For starters, a good regex for innermost parentheses is: `/\(([^()]*)\)/` and contents will be in `$1`

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that in Javascript with a single regex. So extract the innermost parenthesis without the first and last quotes and then split the first capturing group with `', '`.

```
var s = "{{ some_tag('firstarg', 'secondarg', 'thirdarg', 'fourtharg') }}";
var re = /{{\s*(\w+)\s*\(\s*['"]((?:[^'"]*['"]\s*,\s*["'])*[^"']*)['"]\s*\)\s*}}/g;
var results = [];

while(m = re.exec(s)) {
    results.push({'func':m[1], 'param':m[2].split(/['"]\s*,\s*['"]/)})
}

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

MDN examples use a loop to [find successive matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches) with a regexp.

An example using the syntax that arguments are between single quotes and no other single quotes exist:

```
var re = /[^']*'([^']*)'/g  // remember single quoted match

var str = "{{ some_tag('firstarg', 'secondarg', 'thirdarg', 'fourtharg') }}"

var args = []; // args array
var match;     // match array
while(match = re.exec(str))
{   args.push(match[1]);
}

args;  // [firstarg,secondarg,thirdarg,fourtharg]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make sure you get those arguments after `some_tag`, you can leverage the callback method inside a `replace` method:

```
var s = "{{ some_tag('firstarg', 'secondarg', 'thirdarg', 'fourtharg') }}";
var res = [];
s.replace(/some_tag\(([^()]*)\)/, function(m, g1) {
    var splt = g1.replace(/^'([\s\S]*)'$/, '$1').split(/',\s*'/).map(function (t) { res.push(t); });
})
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4);
```

You match the whole `some_tag(...)` with `some_tag\(([^()]*)\)` (or - if the values can have `(` and `)` - with [`some_tag\(([\s\S]*)\)\s*}}`](https://regex101.com/r/pY4qG1/1)), and then remove the initial and final `'`s and split the Group 1 with `'` + space(s)? + `'`.